# Linha vazia no fim quando faço Data Binding - (WPF DataGrid Control + MySQL)

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Estive a implementar o exemplo relativo a este [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/47548d/data-binding-in-wpf-datagrid-control-using-mysql-database/).

Basicamente tenho:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridBind.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridBind"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="620">
<Grid Height="350" Width="625" Background="#FFD1F9EE" >
    <TextBlock Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,15,0,0" Name="textBlockHeading" Text="Produtos" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310"  FontSize="20" FontStretch="Normal"/>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="310" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="625">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,55,0,46" Name="dataGridCustomers" Width="575" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LoadDataBinding}" CanUserResizeRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=idProduto}" Header="Código" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProdutoNome}" Header="Nome" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProdutoPU}" Header="Preço Unit." Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProdutoStock}" Header="Stock" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProdutoStockMin}" Header="Stock Min." Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProdutoStockMax}" Header="Stock Max." Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Load Data" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="487,275,0,0" Name="btnloaddata" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Click="btnloaddata_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

code behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
namespace DataGridBind
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.

    #region MySqlConnection Connection
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #endregion

    #region bind data to DataGrid.
    private void btnloaddata_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!loadData())
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro inesperado ...");
    }
    #endregion

    private bool loadData()
    {
        bool status = false;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select idProduto, ProdutoNome, ProdutoPU, ProdutoStock, ProdutoStockMin, ProdutoStockMax from Produto", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
            dataGridCustomers.DataContext = ds;
            status = true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
}
```

Porque razão é que, tendo eu quatro registos na tabela, me surge uma quinta linha na grid (vazia)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução é bem simples!

Precisa definir no XAML o atributo `CanUserAddRows="False"`. Isso irá impedir de mostrar a linha vazia no final.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,55,0,46" Name="dataGridCustomers" Width="575" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LoadDataBinding}">
```

> Quando esta propriedade é definida como true uma linha em branco será exibida na parte inferior de DataGrid.Um usuário pode digitar um novo item à linha em branco.Adicionando uma nova linha adiciona um item a ItemsSource.Você pode definir valores padrão para o novo item ao tratar o evento de InitializingNewItem e definindo os valores programaticamente.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows(v=vs.110).aspx